# How do i replace the existing contents in the recyclerview with the selected directory's files?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, file-manager

[image]

In the above image, the first tab displays the files/folders in the root directory of the sdcard. I am using the checkbox to select the files. The problem is when I select a folder, I want to replace the `Recyclerview` contents with the contents of the selected folder's files. If the folder has a subfolder, then clicking that should replace the contents again. Basically, I want the functionality of a file explorer here. I also want it to remember which files have been checked as those files will be sent to another device.

The code to display the existing `Recyclerview`is fairly simple. I am assigning an ArrayList of files(inside the root directory) to the `Recyclerview` adapter.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Well if you select a subfolder you could reset the data of the `Adapter`.

Example:

- Current Path: X
- Clicked Folder in that Path: example

Now you would like to list the files / folders of the Path X/example. So you will always store the current path in the adapter and create a method called update or similar where the input is the new path. then you update the adapter and voilah! If the user decides to go from path X/example back to the Path X just cut off the current Path by the last occurence of "/".

I'll demonstrate it to you in pseudocode:

```
class Adapter {
  String path;
  List<String> currFileNames;

  void updateFiles(String destPath) {
    path = destPath;
    currFileNames = //Fetch file names from system
    notifyDataSetChanged()

  }

  void goOneLevelUp() {
    path = //substring path from X/example down to X 
    updateFiles(path)
  }
}
```

If you always want to keep a reference to the "older" fiels which are for example at Path X and not always replace them you could adapt the whole thing as follows:

Create a class which holds a Path and a List fileNames

```
class FileNameHolder {
  String path
  List<String> fileNames
}
```

In the adapter keep the Path but replace the List

```
class Adapter {
  String path;
  List<FileNameHolder> fileNameHolders
  List<String> currFileNames

  void updateFiles(String destPath) {
    path = destPath
    if (fileNameHolders.has(path)) {
      currFileNames =  fileNameHolders.wherePathEquals(path).currFilenames
    } else {
      FileNameHolder holder = new FileNameHolder(path, fetchFileNamesFromSystemForPath(path))
      fileNameHolders.add(fileNameHolder)
      currFileNames = fileNameHolder.currFileNames
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged()
  }

  void goOneLevelUp() {
    path = //substring path from X/example down to X 
    currFileNames =  fileNameHolders.wherePathEquals(path).currFilenames
  }
}
```

Handling the case of `Backnavigation` as you mentioned in your comment:
In the Adapter add a public method called backPressed() like so:

```
   public boolean backPressed() {
      if (path.contains("/")) { //assuming that - continuing our example X would be the root path and X/example would be one level down. so if the path contains a "/" you are not at the root level
        goOneLevelUp()
        return true
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
```

In your `Fragment / Activity` or wherever your `RecyclerView` exists override onBackPressed() like so:

```
@Override
onBackPressed() {
  if (!recyclerView.getAdapter().backPressed()) {
     super.onBackPressed()
  }
}
```

As long as your `RecyclerView Adapter` could "consume" the back press (updating the data) it will return `true`. If however the filepath is at root level it will return `false`, therefore the `superclass onBackPressed` should be invoked (otherwise you wouldn't be able to get out of this view).

**Keep in mind everything is pseudocode and written straight of my mind. No testing or anything. Should work though, otherwise please tell me and I'll edit my answer :)**

Comment: But how do I retain the checked items?

Comment: updated my answer.. hopefully works fine now :). oh and currFileNames holds the fileNames you will display

Comment: Hi. I implemented the part to replace the current directory and that is working great..So thank you for that . Now I have another question. I have added a back button in the fragment that contains the recyclerview. Now i need to convey the back button click(from the fragment) to the recyclerview adapter so that I can change the contents of the recyclerview again. Any help with that?

Comment: i ended up using a different approach.. but it solved my problem. Thanks for all your help

Comment: oh ok :3 but great that I could still help!